# How to manage Heap Space in Java

Tags: java, heap-memory

I'm trying to recursively traverse through my Drive to search some files.
The code is working fine when there are limited folders/files but when I target my search to C drive where in I have lots of files it throws Out of Heap memory.

**Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

1. Please suggest me some good memory management tricks especially when we do recursive calls.
2. Or give me better approach to traverse through directories without recursion.

and I don't want to increase the maximum allowable heap space as it is just like postponing the issue for time being.

Code:

```
void iterateDirectory(String somedir) {


        File dir = new File(somedir);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (int id = 0; id < files.length; id++) {
                if (files[id].isDirectory() == false) 
                {
                   fsTree.add(files[id].toString()); // taking list of files
                } 
                else 
                {
                    iterateFilesInDirectory(files[id].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JeremyHeiler That would probably make things worse, the error says its run out of heap space, not stack space.

Comment: How exactly are you recursing? The directory structure is a 'tree', so a search is usually a depth-first or breadth-first traversal of the tree.

Comment: If you do it right, a depth-first traversal of a tree 100 levels deep will still only have 100 nodes worth of memory occupied at any point of  time.

Comment: Recursion alone does not need any heap space, what objects do you create that need so much memory?

Comment: I'm doing depth search. going till the leaf node directory.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler we know enough to know that the problem is not a stack overflow, but an out of heap space error. Meaning that recursion is not the problem, but rather if breadth search or depth search is being used, or if excessive amounts of data are being stored for each node expansion.

Comment: Post some code. What do you do at each node?

Comment: @Vasant - Look at this tree: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Depth-first-tree.svg - When you are at node 12, what other nodes are *still* being referenced somewhere? If you did it correctly, only nodes 1, 8, and 12 should be referenced. Others should be 'forgotten' so that the GC gets rid of them.

Comment: @Vasant - based on the code you pasted in the EDIT, I don't think switching to an 'iterative' version will change anything for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are limitations as to what recursion can do, namely with respect to stack/heap usage.  Remember that whatever you can do recursively, you can do iteratively; rewrite your code to use an iterative solution instead.

Alternate solution:  There is an interface in `java.nio` that can be used to recursively walk down a filesystem's structure.  Take a look at [this trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html), and [`SimpleFileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html).

Comment: Your solution alleviate the lack of heap memory is to remove memory (that is used to store the tree being explored and where you are on it) from the stack and move it to the heap. Not sure I follow your reasoning.

Comment: @Dunes: I don't remember insinuating that.  In the minimum case, the stack won't be overburdened with an excess of calls, which was my intent. On the other hand, the heap means that there are a *lot* of objects being created that are unnecessary.  We can't postulate where that's taking place, since we don't have code.

Comment: We know enough to know that recursion is not the problem as the error is an OutOfMemoryError and not a StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit, as I see it is this line:

```
fsTree.add(files[id].toString()); // taking list of files
```

It appears that you add *every single file* to a global data structure (`fsTree`), and then search there.

My bet is:

A. It *won't* go away if you 'convert' your recursive function into an iterative one.

B. It *will* go away if, instead of appending to a global data structure and searching in the end, you do the search/matching locally, and only globally cache the matching hits:

```
void iterateDirectory (String somedir, String search_term) {

    File dir = new File(somedir);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (int id = 0; id < files.length; id++) {
            if (files[id].isDirectory() == false) 
            {
               if (/* files[id].isDirectory() MATCHES search_term */)
                 // add to list of matching files:
                 matching_hits.add(files[id].toString());
            } 
            else 
            {
                iterateFilesInDirectory(files[id].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. There is infinite recursion in your code (for example, because you're not processing `.` and/or `..` correctly). If that's the case, you have to fix the code.
2. Your code genuinely requires more heap space than what's available. You have two options:

   - reduce you process's memory requirements (a memory profiler could help you understand what's using all that heap space);
   - increase the heap size by specifying the `-Xmx` JVM option.

Comment: It cannot be '1' because OP has stated that the code works fine for smaller examples.